# CSS issues after upgrading to Angular 14

Tags: angular, migration

Can anyone please help me with the style.scss import error after migrating to angular 14

I followed this doc https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=13.0-14.0 for migration
Review these changes and perform the actions to update your application.

Run ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14 which should bring you to version 14 of Angular.

Angular now uses TypeScript 4.6, read more about any potential breaking changes:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/
Make sure you are using Node 14.15.0 or later

---

```
./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
7 │ @import "~ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles.scss 7:9  root stylesheet

./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: @use rules must be written before any other rules.
  ╷
7 │ @use  "~ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles.scss 7:1  root stylesheet
```

---

styles.scss file

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

/* Importing Bootstrap SCSS file. */
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

/* Importing Datepicker SCSS file. */
@import "~ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker";

/* Importing Bootstrap SCSS file. */
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

/* Importing Datepicker SCSS file. */
@import "~ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker";.
```

---

angular.json file

---

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ClientApp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/css/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "optimization": false,
            "sourceMap": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:development"
            },
            "options": {
              "port": 8056
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```